# Learning electronics

Tags: components

I am perplexed about learning electronics. I have basic understanding of components such as inductors, capacitors, etc. But I don't know how to proceed further in field of electronics. *Please suggest me *resources* and techniques to enhance my aptitude in this subject.

Comment: How did you become good at physics and math?

Comment: I would recommend an electrical engineering degree program :)

Comment: @Harry, physics is a broad subject, there are many other branches like mechanics, optics which have concrete reasoning associated with them, hence I find it easy to grasp, whereas with electronics, it is hard for me to formulate what is going on.

Comment: My point is that you’ve spent countless of hours studying it. There’s no blue/red pill for learning electronics.

Comment: @Selvek, i am already perusing my undergraduates in electronics, but i am not happy with the quality of education.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the concepts you want to learn are incredibly broad. I would suggest first finding a project that intrigues you, and learning what you need to do to complete that project. How comfortable you are with the skills needed for that project will determine how far you delve into any individual concept, which will help you identify where you could potentially improve.

For example, let's say you want to build a robot. If you have little experience with this, your best bet might be to buy something like an Arduino and a pre-assembled chassis with motor driver electronics. You would learn how to write code for the Arduino and connect it to the electronics, and when it's all done, you have a neat little robot. This would give you exposure to basic concepts like the mechanics of small robots, the electronics needed to control them, and the control system needed to command those electronics.

After doing a project like that, you might find yourself saying "gee, I really want stronger motors" which would lead to research on different motors and types of motors as well as bulkier electronics to drive them. Or perhaps you'd find yourself saying "the Arduino was nice but I want to use a different custom system" and then you could research how the Arduino works and figure out how you might replace it with your own system.

The gist of this all is that my recommendation is to complete a project that will expose you to many different paths of learning you could take, then after you finish, choose a path to follow deeper.

Comment: I second that. But, alongside the software side, he should implement hardware as well. OP, try to be creative with your little project. For example, add a proximity sensor to your robot, so that he won't collide with objects in his path. Then, for this to work, you need an analog to digital converter, which could be an A/D IC or just a simple comparator. Then maybe add LEDs, and so on... Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

LTspice is an electronic software simulator (free) where you can draw circuits using the basic components and then simulate the behavior of the whole. In the past, I have advised friends to start tinkering with circuits on the simulator first, they enjoyed it.

Answer (score 1):

Build an amplifier, using bipolar transistors, such as this one:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBJHQe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: While I absolutely agree that building a circuit like this can be extremely educational, a circuit like this can be quite daunting for a beginner. Perhaps OP could start a bit smaller?

Comment: Can this even be done with discrete components? Don't you *need* to do it on silicon? Otherwise a breath on the parts or other.. real life disturbances, will affect the circuit.

Comment: When I started out, at a small telemetry company, designing discrete FAST opamps was part of the skill-set for analog designers. As well as designing FAST (1 MegaSample/second) 10 bit ADCs. I was put to work on Modems (aka BitSyncs/ PLLs/ VGAs/ MatchedFilters). But yes, I have archives of schematics of discrete opamps used  after a FET telemetry Multiplexor, the opamp driving a Sample-hold into the ADC. Not my design.

Comment: regarding a breath upsetting the circuit: this is a gain-of-ten circuit. The open loop gain is mostly in the 2nd stage Q3,Q5. The purpose is to demonstrate a COMPLETE analog circuit: diffpairs, current mirrors, constant current collector loads, emitter followers, and short-circuit protection, plus big-cap stabilization. Will a breath upset this? At the 1 millivolt level, probably. If used as an audio "power" amplifier, not likely. I've built circuits like this, using matched transistors from the Motorola rep, both NPN and PNP pairs. Decades ago.The emitter 100 ohms allows discretes to be used.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Huh, interesting. Thanks for elaborating, much appreciated.