# Hello, this is not my circuit. but I'm playing with it, and I have some questions

Tags: transistors, amplifier, multisim

[image]

hello. First, this is not my circuit. Second, I'm newbie student. I just started studying electronic circuit two weeks ago.

I'm just playing with this Circuit. just poking around..
I have some questions. can you guys help me?

[image]
[image]

in this case, I can see weird graph in oscilloscope. (channel B connected to 'c'in circuit and ground)

[image]

is this graph right?
I thought this graph should look like sine graph...isn't it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. What do you expect the circuit to do?

Comment: well, I thought this circuit is amplifier, so ... I think it should amplify my input voltage...and I just curious about that graph

Comment: Try a 5 mV (or maybe 5 uV) peak-peak input, what results do you get?

Comment: The amplification of this circuit (an operational amplifier) is enormous – 100.000 or so. You had to apply external resistors to limit it. What you see is clipping (the tops of the sins are higher than the supply can deliver.)

Comment: well, Thanks Janka. where do you recommend me to apply resistors?

Comment: @QueenEllery \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ make up a *long-tailed pair* and you should not drive the difference between their bases by more than \$40-60\:\text{mV}\$. Much less is better. These are kind of like a teeter-totter: with both base voltages the same, they split \$Q_3\$'s current evenly between them so both collectors are at the same voltage. But as the base voltage difference moves away from zero, one side starts directing more current in its collector and the other side gets less. This is exponential, so just \$60\:\text{mV}\$ difference can mean perhaps 10X difference in collector currents.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 1mA thru the current source, split into left and right sides of the input diffpair, that 0.5mA making 'reac' be 52 ohms, the gain will be 15,000 / (52 + 52) or about 150X.

This answer has a similar circuit.

[Learning electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/405948/learning-electronics)